# Open Source  bug tracking system на Java

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee

Добрый день.
Есть ли в природе система отслеживания ошибок, разработанная на Java, распространяемая с открытым исходным кодом, желательно использующая Hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте посмотреть в сторону [jTrac](http://jtrac.info/) или [scarab](http://scarab.tigris.org/). Но вообще, я сомневаюсь, что вы сможете найти что-то приличное. Скорее всего, всё что вы найдёте в opensource в этой сфере будет умершим в зародыше.